# How to correctly design home network with private boxes with IPv6?

Tags: networking, vpn, router, ipv6, local-area-network

I finally got a static IPv6 `/64` and I am trying to configure my network for it. I do have a NAS that I'd like to have only accessible to myself under a given domain name. For IPv4, I'd setup VPN at the router.

**Is there an IPv6 solution that wouldn't require VPN while requiring authentication to be able to connect to the NAS?**

Otherwise my intuition would still be to set it up at the router to route to `c00::/7`, take advantage of the ability of IPv6 to assign multiple addresses and have NAS addressed under both public and VPN IPs, protecting it with firewall from the public internet.

In addition, what is the best way to set up DNS for this scenario?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with having IPv6 at home.  I think that would help answer some questions

Comment: The need for IPv6 is self evident: it is the Internet. But a more detailed use case always helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 is still IP. At a very high level, its the same as IPv4, but without NATs or port forwarding.

VPN or not is your decision. Perhaps going without requires more hardening and attention than if hiding behind a VPN. But it can be simpler to not tunnel.

Without a VPN, application level auth and encryption is especially important. Pick your favorite protocol, the usual suspects are popular. https or various object storage protocols built on it. sftp via ssh. smb, which Microsoft claims it is hardened these days.

Unnecessary to assign IP addresses to hosts from both a VPN and not-VPN subnet. Enable routing between these nets. Allow rules in the firewall such that the desired zones can access the NAS. Perhaps allow your LAN, and an ISP you use, but deny your guest network.

Regarding multiple subnets, only one /64? Define an address plan, and share it with your ISP explaining you need more. External services, VPN, internal, WiFi, guest WiFi, couple test nets, and so on.  /56 should be the smallest an ISP allocates to a customer.

Regarding DNS... create AAAA records for hosts?  Not sure what else there is to say here.

Comment: Upon further introspection, I think my problem is I feel internet-exposed services should be more hardened and I don't trust NAS (or potential IoT) to do that. What I hear is that VPN is still the correct solution to that. 

It didn't occured to me that VPN-to-noVPN can be done just via routing, will do. The DNS question was about whether to have public DNS records or do I need to have to run private DNS, but with routing it seems like public is viable.

And I see that I should move on with those questions to SuperUser—but thanks for the answer.